Jmeter: Latency vs load time - am I testing my network instead of the server?
I have noticed that with the increase in the number of threads I am running locally (I am talking about ~80 threads), the latency has increased from 100 to 10149, and the load time has jumped from 180 to 11000 while connect time stays within 0 - 5 range.
This is the definition of latency, as per JMeter docs

Latency. JMeter measures the latency from just before sending the
request to just after the first response has been received. Thus the
time includes all the processing needed to assemble the request as
well as assembling the first part of the response, which in general
will be longer than one byte. Protocol analysers (such as Wireshark)
measure the time when bytes are actually sent/received over the
interface. The JMeter time should be closer to that which is
experienced by a browser or other application client.

What worries me is, the server-side logging, that says, "I am producing the response within 80 - 100ms" [I am not 100% sure it's calculated correctly]
Now I am looking at Jmeter reports and asking myself, what does it show? Is that increase in "response time" just because I am exhausting my local network? And is the server as fast as it was without threads? Is there a way for me to decrease the influence of network travel time when measurements are performed?


Latency == Time To First Byte
Load Time == Time To Last Byte

The formula for load time is:

Time to establish connection + time for the request to reach the server + server processing time + time for the response to reach JMeter

Load Time - Latency == time for the response to reach JMeter
There are several possible reasons:

Your server doesn't tell the full story in the logs, i.e. it reports its own processing time and doesn't include time to wait for external entities like database query
Your request and response are very large and packets are queuing up instead of traveling at full speed
JMeter is not properly configured. It shouldn't be the case for 80 threads, but again, it depends on what threads are doing

Consider enabling monitoring of whatever metrics you can reach using i.e. JMeter PerfMon Plugin and profiler tool or an APM tool on the system under test side.
JMeter won't tell you more than the metrics from the .jtl file
